# Error while installing printer in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04

I have tried to install a canon printer mp6250 but unfortunately I get this

```
Failed to get a list of devices: 'Invalid argument'
```

Comment: How did you try to install this? What exact commands did you enter?

Comment: I was going through the systems setting center and click on the printer and the window came up saying "Failed to get a list of devices: 'Invalid argument'" with no options

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Mint 14.04 KDE. It turned out that the actual cups package wasn't installed. I solved it by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

Comment: Happened to me after 16.04 upgrade, apparently cups was lost during the update so your solution worked perfectly, thanks!